# Jerry doc.$ getelementbyclassname

Tags: java, getelementsbyclassname, jodd, jodd-lagarto

i want to access an element which has no id - just a class.
How can i access it with Jodd? Does Jodd have an equivalent to getelementbyclassname?

The Html looks like the following:

```
 <li class="item list1">
    <a class="link" ... />
    </li>
```

Comment: Hey, would you be so kind to mark the answer if it helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Just access it as you would do using jQuery ([Jerry](http://jodd.org/doc/jerry/index.html) mimics its interface). In this case you will need just to use the appropriate CSS selector:

```
// parse html
Jerry doc = jerry("<li class=\"item list1\"><a class=\"link\"></li>");

// get element by class name
Jerry li = doc.$(".item");
// or
Jerry li = doc.$(".list1");
```

Its simple as that :)